# Mix two projections in the same picture with Asympote

Tags: asymptote

I'm trying to mix several currentprojection in the same picture with Asymptote, but the following example code doesn't work as expected.

```
size(0,25mm);
settings.render = 0;
settings.prc = false;
import solids;
real r = 10;
revolution s = sphere((r,0,0),r);
revolution c = cylinder(O,r,2*r,axis=X);
currentprojection=orthographic(0,100,10);
draw(s,1,frontpen=gray,longitudinalbackpen=gray+solid);
currentprojection=orthographic(10,100,0);
draw(c);
```

I know the question may seem strange and I could use orthographic(10,100,10), but I want to keep the cylinder lines horizontal.